# AIF Inbound ports must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters. Why?

Tags: logging, aif

I'm trying to enable logging for an AIF endpoint which name contains a special character "_". And I'm getting this error message: The name of a port must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters. [@SYS93129]
Validation is in Tables \ AifPort \ validatewrite method.

Does anyone know why is it important? Might it cause any problem to skip the validation?

Thank you!